# Which part of the Constitution was cited in Jacobson v. Williams?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, us-supreme-court, legal-research

Which part of the Constitution did the SCOTUS majority opinion in Jacobson v. Williams cite?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail, please: e.g. case citation, date, area of law at issue etc

Comment: Various parts, although they didn't agree that all of it was relevant https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep197/usrep197011/usrep197011.pdf

Comment: Can you link to the case?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you're asking about [*Jacobson v. Massachusetts*](https://casetext.com/case/henning-jacobson-v-commonwealth-of-massachusetts).

The Supreme Court concluded that the state's vaccine-or-forfeiture statute was a valid exercise of its police power under the Tenth Amendment, that the Fourteenth Amendment did not prohibit the imposition of the forfeiture, and that the preamble to the Constitution does not create any substantive rights.